# Disable Access 2010 subform datasheet highlight bar

Tags: ms-access, subform, datasheet

Is there a way to turn off the blue highlight bar on a datasheet subform in Access 2010? I don't want any records to be highlighted in blue at all, even when I select the record. I like everything else about datasheet view except that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid no. Datasheet view has very limited customization features.
Switch to continuous form

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the response.